# Find all vertices that are included in a simple cycle through a fixed vertex in a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ and a vertex $v \in V$, how to find all vertices $v'$ such that exists a simple cycle $v \to ... \to v' \to ... \to v$? That is, to find the set of vertices $$V' = \{v' : \exists c, \text{c is a simple cycle in G}, v \in c, v' \in c \}$$

I found this question related: [Find all cycles through a given vertex](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60395/find-all-cycles-through-a-given-vertex). I can first find all cycles and then union them to get $V'$. However, is there a more efficient way to do so?

Comment: This is the special case of https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118664/755 where $U=V$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is NP-hard, by reduction from the two disjoint paths problem.

The two disjoint paths problem is as follows:

> Given a directed graph $G$ and $(s_1,t_1),(s_2,t_2)$, find two paths $s_1 \leadsto t_1$ and $s_2 \leadsto t_2$ that are vertex-disjoint (they have no vertex in common).

This problem is NP-hard.

We can reduce two disjoint paths to your problem.  In particular, given $G$ and $(s_1,t_1),(s_2,t_2)$, we construct a new graph $G'$ by adding new vertices $v,v'$ and  adding edges $v \to s_1$, $t_1 \to v'$, $v' \to s_2$, $t_2 \to v$.

Notice that any pair of vertex-disjoint paths $s_1 \leadsto t_1$, $s_2 \leadsto t_2$ will yield a simple cycle

$$v \to s_1 \leadsto t_1 \to v' \to s_2 \leadsto t_2 \to v.$$

Also, within any simple cycle $v \leadsto v' \leadsto v$ we can find simple paths $s_1 \leadsto t_1$, $s_2 \leadsto t_2$ that are vertex-disjoint.  It follows that there exists a simple cycle $v \leadsto v' \leadsto v$ in $G'$ iff there exist two vertex-disjoint paths $s_1 \leadsto t_1$, $s_2 \leadsto t_2$ in $G$.  So, any algorithm for solving your problem would immediately yield an algorithm for solving the two disjoint paths problem.